# How to set data to aria autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, json, typescript, select

I am using aria autocomplete and i want to set data from server to aria autocomplete selection. I fill `selected` property of the aria autocomplete object but do not working. It is my code:

```
JS Code:

    var ariaAC_Obj = AriaAutocomplete(document.getElementById('elem_id'), {
        source: "searchUrl.php",
        onAsyncPrep: (url) => url,
        onAsyncSuccess: (query, xhr, isFirstCall) => {
            return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        },
        asyncMaxResultsParam: 'limit',
        asyncQueryParam: 'q', ...
    });



    function setDataToAriaAutocomplete(data){
        // Ajax req to get data from server
        data = someArray; // result Of Ajax Requset
        ariaAC_Obj.selected = data; // data = [{label: 'my-label3', 'value': 3}]
    }
      
PHP Code:

searchUrl.php
    // some code
    return json_encode([['label' => 'my-label1', 'value' => 1], ['label' => 'my-label2', 'value => 2], and more ... ]);
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

`return json_encode([['label' => 'my-label1', 'value' => 1], ['label' => 'my-label2', 'value => 2], and more ... ]);` I think you should use `echo` instead of `return`. The return statement doesn't write data, it simply returns at the server level.